# docker port forward bind/dns/udp not respond

Tags: docker, udp, bind, portforwarding

I cant get response from anywhere but docker container specific ip or inside container.

my firewall is disabled on virtualbox machine:

```
root@docker-aasaam-web-app:~# ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

On docker machine test docker container ip:

```
root@docker-machine:~# telnet 172.17.0.3 53
Trying 172.17.0.3...
Connected to 172.17.0.3.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

inside container

```
root@014f546c2322:/# telnet 127.0.0.1 53
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

on docker machine test local ip :

```
root@docker-machine:~# telnet 127.0.0.1 53
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

outside of virtualbox

```
sweb@sweb-laptop:~$ ping 192.168.56.160
PING 192.168.56.160 (192.168.56.160) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.160: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.366 ms
^C
--- 192.168.56.160 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.366/0.366/0.366/0.000 ms

sweb@sweb-laptop:~$ telnet 192.168.56.160 53
Trying 192.168.56.160...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

and docker ps is :

```
root@docker-machine:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
dc758771ce15        exampleapp-dns:latest                        "exampleapp-start"           21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:53->53/udp       exampleapp-dns
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. i need to add `--dns=127.0.0.1` to running container for force resolve config.